Is it possible to use Psi4 as a library in a C++ project and run calculation from the project?
I have been trying to connect Psi4 as a library in an Eclipse C++ project and then run a code for a calculation of the energy, for example. After compilation Psi4 from sources I have obtained a build/bin folder where include and lib folder have been located — so I've added them in Eclipse to GCC C++ Compiler — Includes — Include path and to GCC C++ Linker — Library search path and then the word psi4 to Libraries. But something hasn't been right.
In general, is it possible to run a code like this or similar:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <psi4/api/api.h>

int main() {
    psi4::init();

    // Define molecule (Water)
    std::string molecule = R""(
    0 1
    O 0.0 0.0 0.0
    H 0.0 0.0 0.97
    H 0.0 0.77 -0.43
    )"";

    psi4::Molecule mol(molecule);
    double energy = psi4::energy("HF/6-31G", mol);
    
    std::cout << "Energy: " << energy << " Hartree" << std::endl;

    psi4::finalize();
    return 0;
}

(This code can be incorrect.)
